# MobileFirst 8.0 Direct Update not work and the app keep loading

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jndi, mfp, direct-update

Good day,

I upload a web resource archive to MobileFirst Console, I expected my mobile device will receive the direct update notification.

However, my app just keep loading.

I go check the mfp trace.log, it just keep printing

```
[3/9/20 19:52:01:788 MYT] 000000c1 id=         com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils                          1 JNDI Access (global scope) not found in cache for key mfp.cloud.devicelimit
[3/9/20 19:52:01:789 MYT] 000000c1 id=         com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils                          1 globalScopeLookup JNDI Access via globalScopeLookup to mfp.cloud.devicelimit => null
```

I try to google on this error message but didnt get any good result.

I run the following command to generate the web resource file:

```
mfpdev app webupdate --build
```

And then I upload it to MFP Console.

My cordova-plugin-mfp version is as follow:

```
"cordova-plugin-mfp": "^8.0.2020012903"
```

Its Cordova app.

There is no client side log, the console just log nothing until it hit timeout, then it only log timeout message.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate "my app just keep loading" ? Did you get DU popup ? when does app keep loading after DU complete ? what is 'cordova plugin list' command o/p your project has ?
Do you see issue only on Android ?

Comment: I didnt get DU pop up. My app will have a loading gif to loading there, it will keep loading until request timeout. No any console error during its loading. Same apply for IOS.

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar, for the cordova plugin list, do u means all the cordova plugin under my plugins folder?

Comment: How did you generate & upload the web resources archive. Please update the question with this information

Comment: @PanadolChong  Yes what is cordova-plugin-mfp and webview plugin version used in your app . Is it an iONIC or Cordova app ?. Enable the client side logs by calling API WL.Logger.config({ level: 'DEBUG' });  and update the question with logs for more details https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/application-development/client-side-log-collection/

Comment: Hi @manjunathkallannavar, just update my question by add in cordova-plugin-mfp version. There is no log in console. For your information, I found that If I generate the apk with my machine, and generate the web resource with my machine as well, then the direct update will work. Is it a must that the apk and web resource must be from same machine?

Comment: @Srik, just update my question on how I generate and upload the web resource zip file.